# Data Cleaning - Stroop Test: Trying to find a paper than cleans the stroop test for individual questions

Tags: data

I am looking for papers that did data cleaning on stroop test results in terms of individual questions.

For example, for an individual stroop test Q, remove results that took less than 200ms and more than 3000ms.

I used http://doodlegames.com/stroop/ to conduct my stroop test so I have data that looks like this: [image: Excel Sheet showing Data]

I'm planning on using average reaction time but am unsure how to clean my data.